# Can I run 2 data recovery softwares simultaneously?

Tags: data-recovery

Does running two different hard drive recovery softwares (Recuva, TestDisk etc) hamper any chances of data recovery.
Its probably not as I don't think they'd be doing any writing at all. But just to be sure, does it reduce my chances of recovery at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may not, but you're going to thrash the drive with the constant reads and in turn will slow both pieces of software down.  Why not try one, then the other?

Comment: Exactly. I expect there's a pretty good chance that Recuva will be looking at one end of the disk whilst TestDisk is looking at the other, the disk heads will be constantly thrashing back and forth between the two areas under scrutiny. Consequently I expect there's a good chance that running concurrently will take much longer than running consecutively.

Comment: And if this drive is being recovered because you have hardware failure issues, it will probably expire under the abuse, negating the very reason you're trying to run the software in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for one data recovery software at one time. Suppose if you have lost any data stop using the computer and use one data recovery software to retrieve your data. Otherwise if data is overwritten then it would be difficult to retrieve data back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).